# Delphi XE2 incompatible types pointer and PAnsiChar

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am compiling my application in **Delphi XE2**.It was developed in **delphi 7.**. My code is as follows:

```
type
 Name = array[0..100] of PChar;
 PName = ^Name;
var
  HEnt: pHostEnt;
  HName: PName;
  WSAData: TWSAData;
  i: Integer;

begin
     Result := False;
     if WSAStartup($0101, WSAData) <> 0 then begin
     WSAErr := 'Winsock is not responding."';
       Exit;
     end;
    IPaddr := '';
    New(HName);


 if GetHostName(HName^, SizeOf(Name)) = 0 then <-----ERROR
   begin
      HostName := StrPas(HName^);      

      HEnt := GetHostByName(HName^);    
            "
            "
         so on...
   end;
```

When i try to compile the code ,i  get the  following error:
 [image]

When i try this code in another application it works fine in Delphi 7.
How do i convert from character pointer to **PAnsiChar** type to make it run on **Delphi XE2**??.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: I marked it as ERROR just now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My Delphi knowledge might be a little rusty, but as far as I remember:

PChar is (kind of like, not exactly) a pointer to a string in itself, so this type is actually an array of 101 PChars (strings):

`Name = array[0..100] of PChar;`

I think you should change it to `array [0..100] of Char`, or why not declare `HName` as a `PAnsiChar` right from the start?

Comment: If i declare it as array of char then it gives same error. and if HName  is declare as PAnsiChar  then it says "Incompatible types:PAnsiChar and AnsiChar".

Answer (score 6):

This is not the correct way to use `gethostname()`.  Use this instead:

```
var
  HName: array[0..100] of AnsiChar;
  HEnt: pHostEnt;
  WSAData: TWSAData;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  if WSAStartup($0101, WSAData) <> 0 then begin
    WSAErr := 'Winsock is not responding."';
    Exit;
  end;
  IPaddr := '';

  if gethostname(HName, SizeOf(Name)) = 0 then
  begin
    HostName := StrPas(HName);
    HEnt := gethostbyname(HName);
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: ohh ok...i did the changes...thanx a lot:)

Answer (score 2):

yes...i got it:)
I declared HName as **HName:PAnsiChar;** and

```
if GetHostName(PAnsiChar(HName^), SizeOf(Name)) = 0 
HostName := StrPas(PAnsiChar(HName^)); 
HEnt := GetHostByName(PAnsiChar(HName^));
```